# Regression method with high precision

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, precision

I would like to ask suggestions for my data set. As I am not familiar with machine learning or data science, I would like to get help from you guys.

I have four features, about a million rows each of them with one output. The final purpose is to make a fine regression with high precision. I have tried one regression method, and it seems like due to lot of samples there seems to be non-universal regression equation that fits for million rows.

Are there any methods I can try? One idea I thought of is to do multiple regression by truncating data rows, but then what should I do with all these equations to somehow make "one universal" equation or at least, minimize the number of the equation as much as possible to make quasi-universal?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "long row line"? I understood you only have four features per row/sample? Or do you mean the issue that you have a million rows (which to me would mean one million samples.

Comment: Hi, so I have a dataset of four features and output with million lines. You understood it right, I forgot that word "sample"!.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit learn is a great package to do this sort of things (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/)

There exists tons of methods to perform this kind of regression task. The first I would try are LinearRegression, RandomForestRegressor, AdaBoost.

Now, you must prescribe a relevant metric to measure the success of the regression (l2 distance is the most common, but it may be ill-suited for your problem).

Comment: Thank you! Lemme try that :)